# Unable to include excluded file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've been trying to include a file that had been included in my version of the software previously. File has been excluded using solution explorer from a Visual Studio project connected to the TFS version control system. Project is a Web Application.

When I'm trying to include it back again from the Visual Studio (2017) context menu of the item, **'Include In Project'** option is inactive for some reason.

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the project type? You said the file was excluded in TFS, that's not the same thing as being excluded from the project file - is it excluded in both? Are you using Git with TFS, or are you using TFS's own source-control (e.g. Source Control Explorer works)?

Comment: @Dai , question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always include a file manually in the .csproj file of the respective project. Add following in  the .csproj file under relevant `<ItemGroup>`s

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ShiftRoster.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ShiftRoster.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ShiftRoster.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ShiftRoster.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="ShiftRoster.aspx" />
```